# Borrow checker doesn't realize that `clear` drops reference to local variable

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

The following code reads space-delimited records from stdin, and writes comma-delimited records to stdout.  Even with optimized builds it's rather slow (about twice as slow as using, say, awk).

```
use std::io::BufRead;

fn main() {
    let stdin = std::io::stdin();
    for line in stdin.lock().lines().map(|x| x.unwrap()) {
        let fields: Vec<_> = line.split(' ').collect();
        println!("{}", fields.join(","));
    }
}
```

One obvious improvement would be to use `itertools` to join without allocating a vector (the `collect` call causes an allocation).  However, I tried a different approach:

```
fn main() {
    let stdin = std::io::stdin();
    let mut cache = Vec::<&str>::new();
    for line in stdin.lock().lines().map(|x| x.unwrap()) {
        cache.extend(line.split(' '));
        println!("{}", cache.join(","));
        cache.clear();
    }
}
```

This version tries to reuse the same vector over and over.  Unfortunately, the compiler complains:

```
error: `line` does not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:7:22
  |
7 |         cache.extend(line.split(' '));
  |                      ^^^^
  |
note: reference must be valid for the block suffix following statement 1 at 5:39...
 --> src/main.rs:5:40
  |
5 |     let mut cache = Vec::<&str>::new();
  |                                        ^
note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the for at 6:4
 --> src/main.rs:6:5
  |
6 |     for line in stdin.lock().lines().map(|x| x.unwrap()) {
  |     ^

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Which of course makes sense: the `line` variable is only alive in the body of the `for` loop, whereas `cache` keeps a pointer into it across iterations.  But that error still looks spurious to me: since the cache is `clear`ed after each iteration, no reference to `line` can be kept, right?

How can I tell the borrow checker about this?

Comment: “no reference to `line` can be kept, right?” → right. But how does the borrowck knows that?

Comment: I would note that `line` is an allocated `String`: each iteration would *still* requires a fresh memory allocation even if the `Vec` caching worked.

Comment: @mcarton: Exactly: that's why I'm asking how I can tell the borrow checker about it :)

Comment: @MatthieuM. I'd be curious to know a way to reuse that string's memory as well :) But it might be better as a separate question.

Comment: @Clément to avoid reallocating `line` every time, you should use `read_line` instead of `lines`

Comment: @mcarton Ooh, great idea :) Thanks!

Comment: Although interestingly, using read_line is measurably slower.  I wonder why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only way to do this is to use [`transmute`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.transmute.html) to change the `Vec<&'a str>` into a `Vec<&'b str>`. `transmute` is unsafe and Rust will not raise an error if you forget the call to `clear` here. You might want to extend the `unsafe` block up to after the call to `clear` to make it clear (no pun intended) where the code returns to "safe land".

```
use std::io::BufRead;
use std::mem;

fn main() {
    let stdin = std::io::stdin();
    let mut cache = Vec::<&str>::new();
    for line in stdin.lock().lines().map(|x| x.unwrap()) {
        let cache: &mut Vec<&str> = unsafe { mem::transmute(&mut cache) };
        cache.extend(line.split(' '));
        println!("{}", cache.join(","));
        cache.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: This should have a safe abstraction I think, but I can't think of any existing one. For example [recycler](https://github.com/frankmcsherry/recycler/issues/3#issue-74243434) probably has the same lifetime restriction.

Answer (score 9):

In this case Rust doesn't know what you're trying to do. Unfortunately, `.clear()` does not affect how `.extend()` is checked.

The `cache` is a "vector of strings that live as long as the main function", but in `extend()` calls you're appending "strings that live only as long as one loop iteration", so that's a type mismatch. The call to `.clear()` doesn't change the types.

Usually such limited-time uses are expressed by making a long-lived opaque object that enables access to its memory by borrowing a temporary object with the right lifetime, like `RefCell.borrow()` gives a temporary `Ref` object. Implementation of that would be a bit involved and would require unsafe methods for recycling `Vec`'s internal memory.

In this case an alternative solution could be to avoid any allocations at all (`.join()` allocates too) and stream the printing thanks to `Peekable` iterator wrapper:

```
for line in stdin.lock().lines().map(|x| x.unwrap()) {
    let mut fields = line.split(' ').peekable();
    while let Some(field) = fields.next() {
        print!("{}", field);
        if fields.peek().is_some() {
            print!(",");
        }
    }
    print!("\n");
}
```

BTW: Francis' answer with `transmute` is good too. You can use `unsafe` to say you know what you're doing and override the lifetime check.

Answer (score 5):

Itertools has [`.format()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.5.2/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.format) for the purpose of lazy formatting, which skips allocating a string too.

```
use std::io::BufRead;
use itertools::Itertools;

fn main() {
    let stdin = std::io::stdin();
    for line in stdin.lock().lines().map(|x| x.unwrap()) {
        println!("{}", line.split(' ').format(","));
    }
}
```

---

A digression, something like this is a “safe abstraction” in the littlest sense of the solution in another answer here:

```
fn repurpose<'a, T: ?Sized>(mut v: Vec<&T>) -> Vec<&'a T> {
    v.clear();
    unsafe {
        transmute(v)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to refrain from storing references altogether, and to store indices instead. This trick can also be useful in other data structure contexts, so this might be a nice opportunity to try it out.

```
use std::io::BufRead;

fn main() {
    let stdin = std::io::stdin();
    let mut cache = Vec::new();
    for line in stdin.lock().lines().map(|x| x.unwrap()) {
        cache.push(0);
        cache.extend(line.match_indices(' ').map(|x| x.0 + 1));
        // cache now contains the indices where new words start

        // do something with this information
        for i in 0..(cache.len() - 1) {
            print!("{},", &line[cache[i]..(cache[i + 1] - 1)]);
        }
        println!("{}", &line[*cache.last().unwrap()..]);
        cache.clear();
    }
}
```

---

Though you made the remark yourself in the question, I feel the need to point out that there are more elegant methods to do this using iterators, that might avoid the allocation of a vector altogether.

The approach above was inspired by a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61339014/how-to-tell-the-borrow-checker-that-a-cleared-vec-contains-no-borrows), and becomes more useful if you need to do something more complicated than printing.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on Francis's answer about using `transmute()`, this could be safely abstracted, I think, with this simple function:

```
pub fn zombie_vec<'a, 'b, T: ?Sized>(mut data: Vec<&'a T>) -> Vec<&'b T> {
    data.clear();
    unsafe {
        std::mem::transmute(data)
    }
}
```

Using this, the original code would be:

```
fn main() {
    let stdin = std::io::stdin();
    let mut cache0 = Vec::<&str>::new();
    for line in stdin.lock().lines().map(|x| x.unwrap()) {
        let mut cache = cache0; // into the loop
        cache.extend(line.split(' '));
        println!("{}", cache.join(","));
        cache0 = zombie_vec(cache); // out of the loop
    }
}
```

You need to move the outer vector into every loop iteration, and restore it back to before you finish, while safely erasing the local lifetime.

Answer (score -1):

The safe solution is to use [`.drain(..)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.drain) instead of `.clear()` where `..` is a "full range". It returns an iterator, so drained elements can be processed in a loop. It is also available for other collections (`String`, `HashMap`, etc.)

```
fn main() {
    let mut cache = Vec::<&str>::new();
    for line in ["first line allocates for", "second"].iter() {
        println!("Size and capacity: {}/{}", cache.len(), cache.capacity());
        cache.extend(line.split(' '));
        println!("    {}", cache.join(","));
        cache.drain(..);
    }
}
```