# How to tell the borrow checker that a cleared Vec contains no borrows?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm processing a massive TSV (tab separated values) file and want to do this as efficiently as possible. To that end, I thought I'd prevent allocation of a new `Vec` for every line by pre-allocating it before the loop:

```rust
let mut line = String::new();
let mut fields = Vec::with_capacity(headers.len());
while reader.read_line(&mut line)? > 0 {
    fields.extend(line.split('\t'));
    // do something with fields
    fields.clear();
}
```

Naturally, the borrow checker isn't amused, because we're overwriting `line` while `fields` may still have references into it:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `line` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:66:28
   |
66 |     while reader.read_line(&mut line)? > 0 {
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
67 |         fields.extend(line.split('\t'));
   |         ------        ---- immutable borrow occurs here
   |         |
   |         immutable borrow later used here
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5a7aa6439165e7ce4f0420e13708f676))

This isn't actually a problem because `fields.clear();` removes all references, so at the start of the loop when `read_line(&mut line)` is called, `fields` does not actually borrow anything from `line`.

But how do I inform the borrow checker of this?

Comment: Maybe look at how it works in `csv`? Or just straight use `csv` setting a custom separators? It has recipes for amortised allocations.

Comment: `csv` also does more work which I don't need, like handling quoted strings, so I figured the manual way would be faster. Besides parsing there's really very little processing that I'm doing here.

Comment: I remember that I saw cases where to my surprise the allocation in the loop was completely optimised away, so maybe this isn't needed. I also wonder what exactly you are doing at "do something with fields" – does this really require a `Vec`, or could you simply use the iterator directly?

Comment: @SvenMarnach I am taking the value of some fields (whose indices I deduced from the headers) and aggregating them. I could indeed use the iterator directly but it would be cumbersome, because I'd be relying on a particular field order. In any case, my optimization may well be premature, but I'm still interested in the answer to this question for educational purposes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem looks similar to the one described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39946430/borrow-checker-doesnt-realize-that-clear-drops-reference-to-local-variable).

In addition to the answers there (lifetime transmutations, refcells), depending on the Complex Operation you commented out, you might not need to store references to `line` at all. Consider, for example, the following modification of your playground code:

```
use std::io::BufRead;

fn main() -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    let headers = vec![1,2,3,4];
    let mut reader = std::io::BufReader::new(std::fs::File::open("foo.txt")?);
    let mut fields = Vec::with_capacity(headers.len());
    loop {
        let mut line = String::new();
        if reader.read_line(&mut line)? == 0 {
            break;
        }
        fields.push(0);
        fields.extend(line.match_indices('\t').map(|x| x.0 + 1));
        // do something with fields
        // each element of fields starts a field; you can use the next
        // element of fields to find the end of the field.
        // (make sure to account for the \t, and the last field having no
        // 'next' element in fields.
        fields.clear();
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Hmm, the old "storing indices instead of references" trick. Yep, that should work.

Comment: Would you be willing to adapt this answer and move it to the other question? Ideally all answers would be aggregated on the one question, and other questions with the same or similar answers be linked together. That helps future askers to find answers to their questions more easily and reduces the maintenance burden if something changes in the future, compared to having related answers spread between multiple questions.

Comment: Sure. What do you mean by "move" in this context? I am fairly new to commenting, but I can make a new answer there in the spirit of this one, if that's desireable.

Comment: That's just what I meant (making a new answer on the other question). If this question is marked as a duplicate of the other question, it would be in the spirit of things to also delete *this* answer (so as to help funnel people to the question with more answers); however, you are not obligated to.

Comment: I've made an answer in the other post. I hesitate to completely delete this one though, since the other person's code for `// do something with fields` is simple enough that storing indices seems unnecessarily complicated, so I expect the answer to be buried there. Propose to let them coexist.